# Поясните что за конструкция? ${'

Tags: php

```
$rand = new rand($db, $id);
${'rand__' . $rand->getName()} = explode(PHP_EOL, $rand->getValue());
```

В этом фрагменте мы получаем строки от $rand->getValue(), далее разбиваем их на массив дабы каждая строка была в каждом элементе массива, но что проиходит в

```
${'rand__' . $rand->getName()}
```

?

Comment: а вы не пробовали [документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php) читать?

Comment: если, например, `getName` вернет `1`, то `${'rand__' . 1}` будет равносильно `$rand__1`

Comment: Еще и плюсует кто-то.

Answer (score 3):

Выражение в фигурных скобках вычисляется, затем получившаяся строка используется в качестве имени переменной, после чего берётся знчаение данной переменной.

На всякий случай отмечу, что использование такой конструкции потенциально небезопасно и так точно не следует поступать с данными, пришедшими от пользователя.